# Prototypical Chaining in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, this, code-reuse

Currently trying to add $1 to my Tween every time the makeMoney method is called but instead I receive an error that the makeMoney method is not a function. I have a hunch that it has to do with `this` but I have tried to bind 'this' to the makeMoney method to no avail. This truly seems like it should be simple but I am coming up empty.

```
var Tween = function() {
    Adolescent.call(this);
    this.age  =  12;
    this.job = 'annoy';
    this.allowance = 5;

};
Tween.prototype.makeMoney = function(){

    return this.allowance ++;
}

Tween.prototype = Object.create(Adolescent.prototype);
Tween.prototype.constructor = Tween;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here is first you're adding function to the prototype of the object Tween, and then, you're overwriting whole prototype object with `Object.create(Adolescent.prototype)`. That is why it's undefined.

Instead do the inheritance before extending the prototype.

```
var Tween = function() {
    Adolescent.call(this);
    this.age  =  12;
    this.job = 'annoy';
    this.allowance = 5;

};

Tween.prototype = Object.create(Adolescent.prototype);
Tween.prototype.constructor = Tween;

Tween.prototype.makeMoney = function(){

    return this.allowance ++;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't imagine the placement would matter. Clearly it matters but conceptually why?

Comment: Well, it's quite logical. First you're making the inheritance and then expand the prototype. `Object.create` creates a new object, that's the bottom line here

Comment: @DLF85: Remember that `prototype` is just a property (one that the `new` operator uses, but still, just a boring old property), and the thing attached to it is just an object. Functions have an object there by default, which (to set up inheritance) we have to replace. So just as `a = {}; a.foo = "bar"; a = {};` means we end up with an object on `a` with no `foo` property...